# css images are not showing up

Tags: css, image, position, fixed

I can't figure out why images in bottom of the page are not visible. One is in the right corner and others are those in drop menu in middle. Here's the page: http://nettisivut.eu5.org/set2/glassy.php

html right corner:

```
<div id="yhteys">

<img class="bottom" src="/img/ota yhteyttäx.gif" width="109px" height="42px">
<img class="top" src="/img/ota yhteyttä.gif" width="109px" height="42px">
```

css:

```
#yhteys {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:4%;
height:42px;
width:11%;
z-index:9999;
}

#yhteys img {
position: fixed;
left: 4%;
bottom: -0px;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

#yhteys img.top:hover {
opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: You have spaces in the src of images. Correct that.

Comment: Okay. I took the spaces away from images. Still not working. In dreamweaver they look just fine :/ Not in browser or online.

Comment: I think that's because of the special character in the src also,remove or replace it

Comment: i don't think it's the characters...please post the directory structure for clarity!

Comment: Show us the file names of the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented one case and found out that you're using the wrong extension `src="/img/otayhteyttä.png"` worked in one case. You should confirm the file extensions. Check it and report!

**EDITED**

change

```
<div id="yhteys">
    <img class="bottom" width="109px" height="42px" src="/img/otayhteyttax.gif"></img>
    <img class="top" width="109px" height="42px" src="/img/otayhteytta.gif"></img>
```

to the following

```
<div id="yhteys">
    <img class="bottom" width="109px" height="42px" src="img/otayhteyttax.gif"></img>
    <img class="top" width="109px" height="42px" src="img/otayhteytta.gif"></img>
```

what you're doing wrong is you are trying to access /imgs directory that is nettisivut.eu5.org/imgs/ which doesn't exist or doesn't include your files. to access the imgs directory in the set2 directory, refer to imgs/. This is called a relative address and it is interpreted starting from the current directory, i.e set2. But the former one is absolute address and it is interpreted starting form the root of the website.

I hope it is clearer now?

Comment: Weird because there is no png version of the image in img directory.
There is one in other img folder in other direction in same main direction so can it be that they get messed in server.

Comment: i accessed /img of your site! its open by the way.... and i saw [IMG] otayhteyttä.png            13-Jun-2014 14:19   14K

Comment: Yep it is in other folder for different page

Comment: and your src specifies /img means that the browser fetch the image from http://nettisivut.eu5.org/img/ ... one case worked for me! You try more on it!

Comment: and the gif file in the set2 dir ends with a.gif not ä.png

Comment: I changed img direction's name to imgs. No help.

Comment: Works now :) Looks like it was about img directory. Second img folder in sub direction messed it up. Easiest way was to put copies of the images into both img folders. Thanks for pointing the png-gif stuff out!

Comment: and voting up answers help the answerer and the site! you should get used to it!

Comment: Ah. I'm not using this site too often. Where I vote?

Comment: there is a number with up and down arrows at the start of my answer! and a right mark too!..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you no to use names with spaces or special characters, try by renaming the file like this

```
<img class="bottom" src="/img/ota_yhteyttax.gif" width="109px" height="42px">
```

Hope to help you...

Comment: Yeah I just changed the names but no difference

Comment: You still using this letter "ä" change it for this "a" <img class="top" src="/img/otayhteytta.gif" width="109px" height="42px">

Comment: I took all Ä:s away too. I don't know is it about absolute positioning of bottom bar. I've used this same technique in other pages with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

try not to use Umlaut in css try to use english name and dont use space...

Comment: I took them away and no help